# What is the Cayley graph for alternating group A6?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, terminology, visualization, cayley-graphs

According to [ATLAS of Group Representations](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/alt/A6/), the alternating group $A_6$ is a group of order 360 which has presentation
$$
\langle a,b \mid a^2 = b^4 = (ab)^5 = (ab^2)^5 = 1 \rangle.
$$
If we draw its Cayley graph using these two generators, the 4-order element $b$ will induce regular quadrilaterals in the graph. Further if we shrink each quadrilaterals to a vertex, it is not hard to see from the relations that the resulting graph consists of regular pentagons with 6 meeting at each vertex. I've found the graph very similar to [120-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/120-cell). However they are different because this graph is expected to have 90 = 360/4 vertices while the 120-cell has 600 ones.

So my questions are:

1. Does this graph have a name?
2. Is there any picture on the internet that visualizes it?

**Edit:** it should be 6, instead of 4, pentagons meeting at a vertex

Comment: I'm not so sure it is a good idea to think of the cycles in the graphs as regular quadrilaterals and regular pentagons. The graph is (probably) not planar, and can (probably) not be embedded in 3-dimensional space in a way to make each of the obvious cycles a regular polygon in some plane. Furthermore, it is not clear to me that you even have four 5-cycles meeting at each vertex in the shrunken graph - two non-adjacent 5-cycles meet at each vertex, but what are the faces between them? $(ab (ab^2)^{-1})^4=e$ so it seems to be 8-cycles.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis you raised some good questions. Yes, it is very likely impossible to be a polytope in 3-dimensional space, but could be in 4-dimensional space. Your can find answer to your last two doubt in the [visualization of 120-cell](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/Schlegel_wireframe_120-cell.png/360px-Schlegel_wireframe_120-cell.png). Two adjacent pentagons gives a 8-cycle. Regard

Comment: Imagine your graph nicely drawn on some surface. Count the number of edges and count up the pentagons as faces. Then use the Euler characteristic to calculate the genus of the surface.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yes, they are not adjacent. But I don't see any problem in it. Why should we not allow any non-adjacent pentagons? The 120-cell also has non-adjacent pentagons. Moreover, in 120-cell, *any* two edges meet at a vertex induce a pentagon. So analogously, you may find the face bordered by $ab$ and $ab^2$. To be honest, I don't understand your denotation for the edges. In the shrunk graph, all edges present the 2-order element $a$. Also, remark that $(ab)$ induces four pentagons and $ab^2$ induces two meeting at a specific vertex.

Comment: @Zelox You're right. I've deleted my previous comment. Before contracting the $b$ edges, each of these edges is part of a 4-cycle of $b$ edges, and also of a 10-cycle of the type $(ab)^5$. If you had them all in one plane after the contraction, you'd have 4 pentagons meeting at the resulting vertex. But more than that, $(ab^2)^5=e$ means that even the 'diagonally opposite' pairs of edges meeting at that vertex are also part of a pentagon. So really you have 6 pentagons meeting at each vertex - any two of the four edges are part of some 5-cycle.